# Find unclosed HTML tags

Tags: html, validation

I've been editing a lot of HTML pages with basic text editor, notepad.
When I went to validate them the validation service is saying there's a `div` tag that is not closed. I tend to find automatic error reports such as these don't tend to be too reliable, i.e they will give you a line number and the error but often times the error is actually in another part of the file entirely.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to find the closing tag for an opened HTML tag. For example, you click on a tag then click a shortcut, and the program will jump to the closing tag. I know this functionality is in homesite, but I don't have homesite, and its a bit of a bulky program anyway.

To sum up, I would like to know how to find html tags that don't have closing tags.

Comment: phew, in the end i bunged in a closing div right at the end, and it seemed to satisfy the validator, hurrah, thanks for your suggestions guys!

Answer (score 46):

If you save your HTML as `page.xhtml` (instead of `page.html`), the browser (Firefox/Chrome or Opera) should find the un-closed tags for you without the need for a validator. Just remember to rename them `.html` before serving them online - IE doesn't support `.xhtml` files yet.

**Edit (3 years later):** This post's still getting comments/upvotes so a slight amendment. IE9 and IE10 do now support xhtml files.

Comment: 3 years later.... still supporting IE8.. having issues.. so this comes to rescue..

Comment: Not working as expected to me. As It is giving many error due to HTML5 doctype. Other error about entity which can pass. Before reaching to unclosed tag, possibly need to correct many things from page.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash doctype shouldn't matter, and you shouldn't need entities if you're using UTF-8.

For this trick to work you need to adhere to stricter definitions in HTML5 rather than the loose default - e.g. [HTML5 Polyglot](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-xhtml-author-guide/) or [(x)HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html) but this typically just means using "/>" instead of ">" at the end of self-closing tags (img, input, link, etc.)

Comment: You don't need valid XHTML5 as browser's are simple "well-formedness" checkers, not validators - plain ol' HTML5 should work fine with a tiny tweak or two.

Comment: It complained even about <link alternative feed>. I removed 5-6 things but still was in problem, so quit for later.

Comment: Yep, I upvoted! Because PhpStorm highlighted all errors! That's made my day! Thank you

Answer (score 16):

Use the firefox view source - wrong code will be in different color

Comment: this feature of firefox is very handy, makes firefox special

Answer (score 9):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) - never had any problems with it and also never had any unclosed html tag with it.

You can just click on any element and see if it has a closing tag. Also you can do this: click on "TextFX"(left from plugins in navigation) -> click on "Text FX HTML Tidy" -> click on lets say hmm "TiDy clean Document - wrap". That should fix your html document, aka close all unclosed elements.

Comment: thanks! i will try it, i actually have it installed, but didnt know it could do this.

Comment: @mackx You can just click on any element and see if it has a closing tag. Also you can do this: click on "TextFX"(left from plugins in navigation) -> click on "Text FX HTML Tidy" -> click on lets say hmm "TiDy clean Document - wrap". That should fix your html document, aka close all unclosed elements.

Comment: EditPad Pro. does the same.  It also supports RegEx and selection by column.

Answer (score 5):

http://validator.w3.org/

Does more than just unclosed tags. Should be used by all front-end developers, IMO.

Comment: If I understand him correctly I think he said he's already using the validator and is looking for a local alternative.

Comment: i should have mentioned, that this is the service i used that found the error in the first place, it found the unclosed tags, but im finding it hard to track down the actual tag that is not closed, maybe im just not reading the error report right

Comment: Try to checking the 'Show Source' and it should help. If your page contains several errors, this validator can choke out and the report isn't as helpful. Depending on your IDE though the syntax highlighting and/or tag collapsing should get you the rest of the way - given that is low tech.

Answer (score 2):

I am using two online-tool, which work very fine.
[jona.ca](http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder) and [tormus.com](http://www.tormus.com/tools/div_checker)

Answer (score 1):

[CSE HTML Validator Lite](https://www.freehtmlvalidator.com/) is a free lightweight editor (for Windows) that will check your HTML (just press F6) and find missing end tags and other problems. You can also press Ctrl+M on a start tag or end tag and it will take you to the matching start or end tag.

A simple online service that will also do this (and more) is [OnlineWebCheck.com](http://www.OnlineWebCheck.com/). There are other online services but in my opinion the one I just mentioned is the simplest one to use and understand.

Full disclosure: I am the developer of CSE HTML Validator Lite and http://www.OnlineWebCheck.com/ which is based on CSE HTML Validator.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is very messy, not prettified nor indented, v.Nu (as seen at https://validator.w3.org/nu/) will often get confused (for instance if there's an extre closing tag, it may not manage to select the one which is really wrong).

One solution is code folding: by collapsing all the code which is marked as a child of a certain node, you can often easily spot some incorrect hierarchy.

An example of editor which supports code folding is [Kate editor](https://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kate/): see the arrows on the left in their screenshot.
[image: Kate screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

> free lightweight html editors ... online html validation services that can highlight unclosed tags?

Use [linter-vnu](https://atom.io/packages/linter-vnu).

linter-vnu is a package for the Atom editor that uses the Nu Html Checker (v.Nu) to validate HTML or XHTML documents.

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of linter-vnu.

linter-vnu uses another Atom package, linter, to integrate v.Nu and Atom.

For example, if you open the following `test.html` file in Atom:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Test HTML document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

(with a deliberately missing closing `</div>` tag)

then Atom (or rather, linter-vnu, thanks to linter and v.Nu) displays the following error messages:

- Unclosed element “div”. at line 8 col 1 in test.html
- End tag for  “body” seen, but there were unclosed elements. at line 10 col 1 in test.html

and marks those lines in the editor with red dots.

If you click the "at..." (hyperlinked text) in the error message, the editor insertion point moves to the corresponding line, and a popup appears under the line, with the error text ('Unclosed element "div".').

If you save your HTML document with the file extension `.xhtml`, and open it in Atom, then v.Nu validates your document as XHTML (XML) rather than HTML, with slightly different messages. In this case, just one error message:

- required character (found “b”) (expected “d”) at line 10 col 3

where line 10 contains the closing `</body>` tag. v.Nu was expecting a `</div>` tag instead; it was happy with `</` - it was expecting a closing tag - but it was expecting the element name to begin with "d" for "div", not "b" for "body".

I make the following claims, as of November 2016:

- [v.Nu is the best option for validating (X)HTML(5)](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/251#issuecomment-192209209).
- linter-vnu is the best option for interactively harnessing v.Nu in an editor. linter-vnu itself is trivial; it's just a few lines of "glue" code. What makes it the best option is the Atom editor and the Atom linter package.

I welcome counterclaims and questions about these claims. I'd be happy to be proven wrong and be shown something better. Especially if, like v.Nu and linter-vnu, it's free.